# change HTML scrollbar color when using -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, scrollbar

I have a iOS app that has a WebKit webview (WKWebView) and I want to change the color of the scrollbar in my HTML with CSS while still retaining the touch / throw acceleration scrolling.

I have tried using:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #ff4872;
}
```

...but to no avail. Because it doesn't change the color unless I set the webkit scrolling setting to scroll:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: scroll;
```

...which takes away the Safari-like acceleration scrolling. I would like a pure CSS solution if possible, but I can do JavaScript or JQuery if that is the only option.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rmcadbmq/3/

Comment: can you post your html or JsFiddele code please

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rmcadbmq/3/

Comment: @quemeful I'm having this same issue... did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Using Below code you will solve your issue

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);     
    border-radius: 10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Comment: That code works to change the color. But the main problem is, it requires me to change the -webkit-overflow-scrolling to "scroll" instead of "touch" so I lose the Safari-like scroll acceleration.

Comment: Please use of !important of every where then i think your problem wil be solve.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will work for you:

```
.scrollContainer::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #ff4872; 
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(112,0222,0,0.5);

}
.scrollContainer {
    font-size: 2em;
    width: 300px;
    height: 440px;
    background-color: #eee;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.scrollTest {
    width: 270px;
    height: 440px; 
}
```

Comment: try it on a touch screen device...it loses touch momentum scrolling: https://jsfiddle.net/rmcadbmq/10/

Comment: What is your actual problem?. I think it solved the color issue

Comment: the problem is when I can't change the color when the -webkit-overflow-scrolling is set to "touch" ... I switch it to "scroll" for jsfiddle...10 above

Comment: doesn't have momentum scrolling on touch screen devices ... I think this is a big oversight in webkit css